# Matlab 3D Graph

Tags: matlab, graph

Is there any way to add third dimension to a Graph in Matlab?
I have a Graph object;

```
G = graph(S,T),
```

including XData an YData, is it essentially possible to have a 3D network Graph in Matlab?

The XData, YData and other attributes are being set in the Graph object, like this;

```
p = plot(G);
p.MarkerSize = ones(1,NumberOfNodes); 
p.XData = (an array containing some point according to the return values of a function, the same applies for YData)
```

I need a 3D graph, the to be plotted (possibly).

Comment: How does `graph(S,T)` include X and Y data? Using [graph](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html), `s` and `t` refer to node endpoints for edges. Perhaps you are looking for something like [plot3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html) instead. Please show some code.

Comment: Please post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3D plot can be done using - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html

Now, you need to clearly clarify your inputs - X1, Y1 and Z1